# Excel pie chart for over time

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

Hi,
I was just wondering if I can have "single" pie chart on Excel, which I can choose a specific date (row) and dynamically shows me the relevant pie chart.

In the picture, you see three different pie charts. I want one pie chart which shows a list of dates I can choose and if I choose a date, it updates the pie chart.

How can I accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: One way would be to have a standard row that is plotted.  The values in the row would be lookups against the data based on the specified date (which could be in a pull-down list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, try to use PivotChart and Slicer.

Please add fields as shown in the following picture:

[image]

Then add Slicer and you will get the result:

[image]